# Order of operations for Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1)?

Tags: javascript, math, operator-precedence

In the Code Academy JS course, Dragon Slayer 2/6, the following text is used in the hint to describe the order of operations for the code I included in the title.

> How does this code work?
>
> `Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);`
>
> - First we use Math.random() to create a random number from 0 up to 1. For example, 0.5
> - Then we multiply by 5 to make the random number from 0 up to 5. For >example, 0.5 * 5 = 2.5
> - Next we use Math.floor() to round down to a whole number. For example, >Math.floor( 2.5 ) = 2
> - Finally we add 1 to change the range from between 0 and 4 to between 1 and >5 (up to and including 5)

I've looked this up in several different places ([here](https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/537e64af9c4e9d4d1500026e) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483667/concept-of-math-floormath-random-5-1-what-is-the-true-range-and-why)), and a majority of them either focus on the range that Math.random() produces (which I understand) or confirm the order of operations outlined in the hint, wherein "Math.floor" acts upon "Math.random()*5" prior to the "+1" being added.

It seems to me however that, according to the order of operations that I learned in school, the last two steps should be flipped.  Would that not be the case since "Math.random()*5" and the "+ 1" are both within the parenthesis?

While the difference between these two might not make a difference in the value returned from this particular code, I could see a fundamental change in the order of operation like the one outlined here would cause me some frustration further down the road if I didn't know it.

Comment: The explanation provided for that expression is wrong.

Comment: Everything inside the parentheses wrapping `Math.floor`'s argument should return a float number. So the order should be: `Math.random()` which returns a float between 0 and 0.9999... Then multiply that by 5, then add the 1. Then finally `Math.floor` it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Math.floor() will work on whatever is inside the brackets, after it has been calculated.

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1)
```

is the same as

```
var i = Math.random() * 5;
i += 1;
Math.floor(i);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I felt like I was taking crazy pills, but didn't want to be thinking about something in a way that would bite me later on.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that the wording on the page is wrong.  The last thing that will happen is the `floor` call.  Everything in the parenthesis will be processed first.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I think they mixed up here, and you're right. According to PEMDAS and any mathematics I've ever learned, the +1 comes before the Math.floor function.

Answer (score 0):

The Math.random() function returns a random number in the range [0, 1) that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive).  It can be any thing like 0,.34,.42 etc. 
if you want random number between 0-5. 
you will used Math.Random()*5. This will give you any number like 0,4.43.4.34 but not five.
Then we add 1 like this Math.random() * 5 + 1. Now the chances is you will get a number which is between 0 and 6. But you don't want number above 5. so
you apply floor method which will return largest integer less than or equal to a given number.