# Dragon Slayer - What is meant by Math.floor(Math.random()*2)?

Tags: javascript

so I completed the Dragon Slayer Interactive activity on codecademy, and I was confused at what "Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);" is supposed to do.

Here is the full code for my “Dragon Slayer!” interactive activity.

```
var slaying = true;
var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
var totalDamage = 0;
while (slaying) {
  var damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
  if (youHit) {
    console.log(“You hit the dragon!”);
    totalDamage += damageThisRound;
    if (totalDamage >= 4) {
      console.log(“You slew the dragon!”);
      slaying = false;
    } else {
      youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(“The dragon defeated you!”);
    slaying = false;
  }
}
```

Can you describe what Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) does ?

Comment: It simply generates either number `0` or `1` randomly. I suggest you to look up how `Math.random()` works.

Comment: Remember Cameron, a real **Dragon Slayer** properly formats his question and makes sure everyone can easily read your **[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Keep slaying!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concept of Math.floor(Math.random() \* 5 + 1), what is the true range and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483667/concept-of-math-floormath-random-5-1-what-is-the-true-range-and-why)

Answer (score 0):

he Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1); that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive), which you can then scale to your desired range. The implementation selects the initial seed to the random number generation algorithm; it cannot be chosen or reset by the user.

The Math.floor() function returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number.

```
Math.floor( 45.95); //  45
Math.floor( 45.05); //  45
Math.floor(  4   ); //   4
Math.floor(-45.05); // -46 
Math.floor(-45.95); // -46

Math.random();    // 0.7757860020429985
Math.random() * 2 // number from range 0.x to 1.x

Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); // will give from 0 or 1
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot.  I was a bit confused as to why math.floor(45.95); gives 45 and not 46

Comment: @CameronSu Math.floor will not do a round for positive values as you see in the answer so the ues to do trunc the number another method is math.ceil will do the rounding math.ceil(45.95) => 46